# same filter works in rsyslog but not syslog

Tags: syslog

I have the following filters in new cpanel server with rsyslog to forward log to a central log server(use rsyslog), but these filters didn't work in older cpanel server with syslog. I don't see any error after restart syslog.

```
if $syslogtag contains 'lfd' then @192.168.1.2:514

if $syslogtag contains 'ftp' and $syslogseverity <= 4 then  @192.168.1.2:514

if $syslogtag contains 'dovecot' and $syslogseverity <= 4 then  @192.168.1.2:514
```

Comment: Why is it you are expecting rsyslog configuration to work in syslogd? They are different programs and are configured differently.

Comment: syslogd doesn't have conditional if statements.

Comment: I thought they are sharing the same syntax. I didn't get error when using the same configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rsyslog team intentionally designed their configuration syntax to be as backwards compatible as possible with older BSD based syslogd implementations.  As a result, many configuration options in rsyslog will be parsed without error in syslogd, however, that doesn't mean that syslogd supports the features.

As a general rule, syslogd is a very dumb application, and it supports very minimal filtering on facility and severity.  That's pretty much all it does.  For anything else, you will need to be using rsyslog.

Lack of error does not mean functionality is supported.  Check the `syslog.conf` manpage for details of what (few) features are supported.